# How to convert 1D list to 2D list without using loop?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a float list:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

How can I reshape this list into a multi-dimensional array like:

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0 ,4.0]]
```

without using a loop? Is it possible using `numpy` or any other?

Comment: Use `np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], (4, 3))`.  Much better than `repeat`.  I'll find the dupe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start with a NumPy array, you can use [`numpy.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and then `reshape()` to get the array size/shape you want:

```
> import numpy as np

> a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])

> np.repeat(a, 3).reshape(-1, 3) 

array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can survive not using numpy:

```
orig = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
N = 3
matrix = [[n]*N for n in orig]
```